# Configure connections - Two web apps in the same Tomcat container

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, httpwebrequest, tomcat6

I am developing simultaneously two web applications that would be deployed in a Tomcat 6 container.
My question is simple: Is it possible to configure or manage the number of connections (HTTP requests) allowed by Tomcat to each application?
Actually, I need a total number of connections which does not exceed 12, but I would like also to guarantee at least 4 connections for each application.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to limit the maximum number of **simultaneous** connections then there is a Http Connector setting in Tomcat configuration called **maxThreads**. This defaults to 200 but you could set it to 12 in your case. See [Tomcat Configuration Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html).

If however you want to absolutely throttle the number of active sessions, as in a licensing restriction, you could keep an application scoped (servlet context) variable to add and substract as each session is created and destroyed, thus allowing you to validate any new sessions against this value and accept the session or present a nice message to the user if the quota is exceeded. You can use [HttpSessionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to monitor the creation and destruction of sessions. You could also use an [Interceptor Pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/InterceptingFilter.html) to perform the throttling functionality.

Comment: Thank you Adrian,
 
What I want to do is to set a ***minimal*** number of connections for each application deployed in tomcat.
Actually, other applications could be deployed within the same container, but I wish to ***reserve*** a number of connections to my application.
Is this possible only by configuring Tomcat? Or should I necessarily modify my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @taktako, the connections belong to the container and are allocated to each application to service a request to that application. As long as the system is not under high load your application will be serviced by the container in a timely manner. Otherwise you could start to look at load balancing solutions.

Comment: Also, if you want to comment on an answer you can use the 'add comment' link below the answer, rather than add a new answer yourself. It will allow me to modify the answer in response.